# changes meaning from typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I have the following declaration in my code:

```
typedef QString                          String;
```

Then in another header I do:

```
class MyClass {
  typedef String String;
};
```

and the following error occurs:

```
error: changes meaning of 'String' from 'typedef class QString String' [-fpermissive]
```

What is wrong with using this redeclaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way that type aliases work, it looks to your compiler like you're trying to define `MyClass::String` inside of itself. It gets all confused.

> `[C++11: 7.1.3/6]:` In a given scope, a `typedef` specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to a different type. *[..]*

Here's a complete example:

```
typedef int alias_t;

class T
{
  typedef alias_t alias_t;
};
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/X9Jl9dzH):

> test.cpp:4: error: declaration of 'typedef alias_t T::alias_t'
>   test.cpp:1: error: changes meaning of 'alias_t' from 'typedef int alias_t'

---

I can [fix this example](http://codepad.org/9FapZA4g) by adding the `::` prefix to the existing type:

```
typedef int alias_t;

class T
{
  typedef ::alias_t alias_t;
};
```

---

In your code, that translates to the following:

```
class MyClass
{
   typedef ::String String;
};
```

Comment: as i recall the relevant std rule ensures that a name has just a single meaning in the class scope.

Comment: Just wondering; Wouldn't that break if `MyClass` was in some `namespace myNameSpace`?

Comment: @bitmask Define "that".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "that" := `typedef ::String String`.

Comment: @bitmask I don't see why. Leading `::` is sort of equivalent to Linux `/`, not Linux `../`. But try it and see!

Comment: Sorry, I meant if **both** `MyClass` *and* `String` were sitting inside some namespace. Just forgot to mention the important part.

Comment: @bitmask probably would have to explicitly provide the namespace prefix for `String` then

Comment: @bitmask Oh. You're right. Yes, exactly. :) There's a small syntax limitation there.